# pandas multiply multiple columns to make new df

Tags: python, pandas

I'm starting with two dataframes - one filled with dummy variables for the day of the week, and another filled with dummies for the hour of the day (HE - hour ending).

df1 = days of week = n x m, where n is number of observations, m is 6:

```
    Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat
0   1   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   1   0   0   0   0
2   0   0   1   0   0   0
3   0   0   0   1   0   0
```

df2 = hours of the day = n x l, where n is num of obs, m is 23:

```
    HE1 HE2 HE3 HE4 HE5 ... HE22 HE23
0   1   0   0   0   0   ... 0    0
1   0   1   0   0   0   ... 0    0
2   0   0   1   0   0   ... 0    0
3   0   0   0   1   0   ... 0    0
```

I want to create a new df with dimensions n x (m times l), where m times l = 6*23 = 138:

```
    MonHE1 MonHE2 MonHE3 MonHE4 MonHE5 ... SatHE22 SatHE23
0   1      0      0      0      0      ... 0       0
1   0      1      0      0      0      ... 0       0
2   0      0      1      0      0      ... 0       0
3   0      0      0      1      0      ... 0       0
```

I am successful with this:

```
hoursXdays = pd.DataFrame()
Mon = hours.multiply(days['Mon'],axis='index').add_prefix('Mon')
Tue = hours.multiply(days['Tue'],axis='index').add_prefix('Tue')
Wed = hours.multiply(days['Wed'],axis='index').add_prefix('Wed')
Thu = hours.multiply(days['Thu'],axis='index').add_prefix('Thu')
Fri = hours.multiply(days['Fri'],axis='index').add_prefix('Fri')
Sat = hours.multiply(days['Sat'],axis='index').add_prefix('Sat')
hoursXdays = pd.concat([Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat],axis=1)
```

I'm going to need to do this for a lot more dfs than just these few.  If there's any way I can generalize this, I'd appreciate the help.

Basically, is there a way in pandas to multiply two dataframes dimension n x m, n x l, to make a new df of dimension n x (m times l) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just using for loop here

```
pd.concat([hours.multiply(days[x],axis='index').add_prefix(x) for x in days.columns],1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) and `pd.DataFrame` default constructor

```
d = {a[0]+b[0]: np.array(a[1])*b[1] for a,b in itertools.product(df.to_dict('list').items(), df2.to_dict('list').items())}

dff = pd.DataFrame(d)

MonHE1  MonHE2  ... SatHE22 SatHE23
0   1   0       ... 0       0
1   0   0       ... 0       0
2   0   0       ... 0       0
3   0   0       ... 0       0
```